# Developing grails plugin "No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined" in integration test

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails-orm, grails-plugin

I'm developing a grails plugin, but when I try to create an integration test for a service I'm getting this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:232)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:61)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:223)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:29)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:129)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:232)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:61)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:223)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:290)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:249)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1_closure21.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:195)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:184)
at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:82)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
... 24 more
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: What are you testing? Unit? Integration? Controller? What folder your tests are in matter in grails. I haven't had a great deal of success with testing in grails...

Comment: I tried to create an integration test for a Service...the Service stays in the standard folder of grails, the integration test stays in the standard folder of grails...the error is after I've launched 'grails test-app :integration', I've also annotated the class with @TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)

Comment: If you're creating an integration test you have to put it in a folder called integration, under test/integration I think.

Comment: grails automatically creates it there

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe that this can occur if you've uninstalled Hibernate and you don't specify another transaction manager.  Grails services by default are transactional and Hibernate is what manages that transaction.  If you're not using Hibernate you can set your service to be non-transactional with `def transactional = false`